# ModelValidationException - MVC Codefirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I created controller using entity framework it gave error I commented the HttpPostedFileBase attribute from the class below and tried again, it worked and all the CRUD views were generated. Now when I'm trying to add a new station using following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Create(Station station)
    {
        station.FileName = station.File.FileName;
        station.ImageSize = station.File.ContentLength;
        byte[] data = new byte[station.File.ContentLength];
        station.File.InputStream.Read(data, 0, station.File.ContentLength);
        station.ImageData = data;

            db.Stations.Add(station);
            db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

it gives  exception (shown below):

> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException was
>   unhandled by user code   HResult=-2146233088   Message=One or more
>   validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> MetroTrain.Models.HttpPostedFileBase: : EntityType
>   'HttpPostedFileBase' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType. HttpPostedFileBases: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'HttpPostedFileBases' is based on type 'HttpPostedFileBase' that has
>   no keys defined.
>
> Source=EntityFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate()
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action,
>   EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
>          at MetroTrain.Controllers.StationsController.Create(Station station) in c:\Users\ghousia
>   pc\Desktop\MetroTrain\MetroTrain\Controllers\StationsController.cs:line
>   58
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Object tag)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3c()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.b__3e()
>   InnerException:

The class used (for scaffolding):

```
 public class Station
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Station Name")]
        public string StationName { get; set; }
        public double Distance { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Opening { get; set; }
        public string Connections { get; set; }
        public string Layout { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Tourists Place")]
        public string TouristsPlace { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Tourists Place Image")]
        /////////
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ImageSize { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select file")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// ////
        /// </summary>
        [Display(Name="Line Color")]
        public string LineColor { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You can't and shouldn't save the object `HttpPostedFileBase` to the data store, the error is self explanatory, it says it can't save it as their is no `Key` defined on it.  You should create your own `Entity` to store the details of `HttpPostedFileBase` that you care about

Comment: Thanks. Saying the same thing through code would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAke sure you add an attribute **[NotMapped]** like this.

```
[NotMapped]
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

Comment: But I want to store the image in the database as well.